# Why is This Date Causing an Error?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, calendar

So not so long ago I made my own booking system which displays a calendar on a page with the dates that have been booked but I noticed recently, if one of the bookings goes across two months e.g. 29th March to 4th April the whole thing just crashes / doesn't load and I'm really confused as to why. The date still gets entered into my database but then it breaks.

Here is the code for displaying the calendar (**Note:** I got most of this code from a CodePen and edited it accordingly):

```
<?php

session_start();
ob_start();

$host = "myhostname"; // Host name 
$username = "myusername"; // Mysql username 
$password = ""; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "mydatabase"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "booking"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysqli_select_db($conn, $db_name)or die("cannot select DB");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

?>

<script>
    !function() {

  var today = moment();

  function Calendar(selector, events) {
    this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
    this.events = events;
    this.current = moment().date(1);
    this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
     ev.date = moment(ev.date);
    });
    this.draw();
    var current = document.querySelector('.today');
    if(current) {
      var self = this;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        self.openDay(current);
      }, 500);
    }

  }

  Calendar.prototype.draw = function() {
    //Create Header
    this.drawHeader();

    //Draw Month
    this.drawMonth();
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function() {
    var self = this;
    if(!this.header) {
      //Create the header elements
      this.header = createElement('div', 'header');
      this.header.className = 'header';

      this.title = createElement('h3');

      var right = createElement('div', 'right');
      right.addEventListener('click', function() { self.nextMonth(); });

      var left = createElement('div', 'left');
      left.addEventListener('click', function() { self.prevMonth(); });

      document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 39) {
                event.preventDefault();
                self.nextMonth();
            } else if (event.keyCode === 37) {
                event.preventDefault();
                self.prevMonth();
            }
      });

      //Append the Elements
      this.header.appendChild(this.title); 
      this.header.appendChild(right);
      this.header.appendChild(left);
      this.el.appendChild(this.header);
    }

    this.title.innerHTML = this.current.format('MMMM YYYY');
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() {
    var self = this;


    if(this.month) {
      this.oldMonth = this.month;
      this.oldMonth.className = 'month out ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
      this.oldMonth.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        self.oldMonth.parentNode.removeChild(self.oldMonth);
        self.month = createElement('div', 'month');
        self.backFill();
        self.currentMonth();
        self.fowardFill();
        self.el.appendChild(self.month);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          self.month.className = 'month in ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
        }, 16);
      });
    } else {
        this.month = createElement('div', 'month');
        this.el.appendChild(this.month);
        this.backFill();
        this.currentMonth();
        this.fowardFill();
        this.month.className = 'month new';
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.backFill = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone();
    var dayOfWeek = clone.day();

    if(!dayOfWeek) { return; }

    clone.subtract('days', dayOfWeek);

    for(var i = dayOfWeek; i > 1 ; i--) {
      this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.fowardFill = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone().add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
    var dayOfWeek = clone.day();

    if(dayOfWeek === 7) { return; }

    for(var i = dayOfWeek; i < 7 ; i++) {
      this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.currentMonth = function() {
    var clone = this.current.clone();

    while(clone.month() === this.current.month()) {
      this.drawDay(clone);
      clone.add('days', 1);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.getWeek = function(day) {
    if(!this.week || day.day() === 1) {
      this.week = createElement('div', 'week');
      this.month.appendChild(this.week);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawDay = function(day) {
    var self = this;
    this.getWeek(day);

    //Outer Day
    var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
    outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
      self.openDay(this);
    });

    //Day Name
    var name = createElement('div', 'day-name', day.format('ddd'));

    //Day Number
    var number = createElement('div', 'day-number', day.format('DD'));


    //Events
    var events = createElement('div', 'day-events');
    this.drawEvents(day, events);


    outer.appendChild(name);
    outer.appendChild(number);
    outer.appendChild(events);
    this.week.appendChild(outer);
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawEvents = function(day, element) {
    if(day.month() === this.current.month()) {
      var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
        if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
          memo.push(ev);
        }
        return memo;
      }, []);

      todaysEvents.forEach(function(ev) {
        var evSpan = createElement('span', ev.color);
        element.appendChild(evSpan);
      });
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
    classes = ['day'];
    if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
      classes.push('other');
    } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
      classes.push('today');
    }
    return classes.join(' ');
  }

  Calendar.prototype.openDay = function(el) {
    var details, arrow;
    var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
    var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);

    var currentOpened = document.querySelector('.details');

    //Check to see if there is an open detais box on the current row
    if(currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode === el.parentNode) {
      details = currentOpened;
      arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
    } else {
      //Close the open events on differnt week row
      //currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
      if(currentOpened) {
        currentOpened.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
          currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
        });
        currentOpened.className = 'details out';
      }

      //Create the Details Container
      details = createElement('div', 'details in');

      //Create the arrow
      var arrow = createElement('div', 'arrow');

      //Create the event wrapper

      details.appendChild(arrow);
      el.parentNode.appendChild(details);
    }

    var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
      if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
        memo.push(ev);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []);

    this.renderEvents(todaysEvents, details);

    arrow.style.left = el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft + 27 + 'px';
  }

  Calendar.prototype.renderEvents = function(events, ele) {
    //Remove any events in the current details element
    var currentWrapper = ele.querySelector('.events');
    var wrapper = createElement('div', 'events in' + (currentWrapper ? ' new' : ''));

    events.forEach(function(ev) {
      var div = createElement('div', 'event');
      var span = createElement('span', '', ev.eventName);

      div.appendChild(span);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    });

    if(!events.length) {
      var div = createElement('div', 'event empty');
      var span = createElement('span', '', 'No Booking');

      div.appendChild(span);
      wrapper.appendChild(div);
    }

    if(currentWrapper) {
      currentWrapper.className = 'events out';
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
      currentWrapper.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
        currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
        ele.appendChild(wrapper);
      });
    } else {
      ele.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
  }

  Calendar.prototype.drawLegend = function() {
    var calendars = this.events.map(function(e) {
      return e.calendar + '|' + e.color;
    }).reduce(function(memo, e) {
      if(memo.indexOf(e) === -1) {
        memo.push(e);
      }
      return memo;
    }, []).forEach(function(e) {
      var parts = e.split('|');
      var entry = createElement('span', 'entry ' +  parts[1], parts[0]);
    });
  }

  Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
    this.current.add('months', 1);
    this.next = true;
    this.draw();
  }

  Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
    this.current.subtract('months', 1);
    this.next = false;
    this.draw();
  }

  window.Calendar = Calendar;

  function createElement(tagName, className, innerText) {
    var ele = document.createElement(tagName);
    if(className) {
      ele.className = className;
    }
    if(innerText) {
      ele.innderText = ele.textContent = innerText;
    }
    return ele;
  }
}();

!function() {
  var data = [
      <?php
      $colour = 'blue';
      while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          if($rows['status'] == 'Confirmed') {
              $colour = 'red';
          } else {
              $colour = 'blue';
          }
          ?>
          { eventName: 'Booking Start', calendar: 'Booking <?php echo $rows['status']; ?>', color: '<?php echo $colour; ?>', date: '<?php echo $rows['arrive_date']?>'},
          <?php
          $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['arrive_date']));
          while ($date < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['depart_date']. '-1 day'))) {
              $date++;
              ?>
              { eventName: 'Booked', calendar: 'Booking <?php echo $rows['status']; ?>', color: '<?php echo $colour; ?>', date: '<?php echo $date;?>'},
              <?php
          }
          ?>


    { eventName: 'Booking End', calendar: 'Booking <?php echo $rows['status']; ?>', color: '<?php echo $colour; ?>', date: '<?php echo $rows['depart_date']; ?>'},

    <?php
      }
      ?>
  ];

  var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data);

}();
</script>
```

**EDIT:** In case you need further help this is what an example looks like from the table in the database: [image: Table example]

I can't work out what is causing this problem, I believe it is something to do with the events but I don't know. I was hoping someone a little more experienced could help me out a little.

To see what it looks like visually you can see it live here: https://ryan-simms.com/booking/bookings

**EDIT:** I just found out, doing a test, that if I put in 28th February to the 1st March it doesn't crash but if I change it so it ends on the 2nd March it crashes, really odd.

Comment: Does the CodePen code have the same problem? What is the link? If not: What did you change?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware this is the CodePen https://codepen.io/peanav/pen/ulkof, I'm not so sure the calendar is supposed to be used for multiple dates but just single dates.

Comment: The problem is that there is so much code that we can't even begin to start debugging. Try to narrow down the problem and just the relevant part.

Comment: @Ibu I think I found the part with the error it's the dates between the start and end date causing the problem (where the while loop is) I'm trying to figure out how to change this.

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Solved by editing the `while` loop and using a different method for getting all dates in between two dates. Example code:

```
$start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['arrive_date']. '+1 day'));
$end =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($rows['depart_date']. '-1 day'));
while ($start <= $end) {
    ?>
    { eventName: 'Booked', calendar: 'Booking <?php echo $rows['status']; ?>', color: '<?php echo $colour; ?>', date: '<?php echo $start;?>'},
    <?php
    $start = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 days", strtotime($start)));
}
```